# New to Blender. My simple scene has really long render times

Tags: rendering

I am a Max user and I have been trying to learn blender for the last couple of weeks. I created a simple animation: a rotating sphere with a rock generator applied to it, a few lights and that's it. I got a reasonably powerful computer (threadripper 1950x 16 cores/32 threads). I get a lot of noise in the render and if I tried getting rid of it increasing the samples I get crazy render times. It takes about 8 minutes per frame with 1500 samples (the animation is 1000 frames long) and the render is still really noisy. If I increase the samples the render time goes way way up. A scene like mine would take barely a minute or two in max and vray. I am obviously doing something wrong. Could anybody help me out a bit? Thank you!

Comment: Hard to say what the cause is based on your description. Can you upload your project and add a link to your question? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hello Robert!Thank you so much for your help. Here is a link to the file:

Comment: Hello Robert!Thank you so much for your help. Here is a link to the file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1itp_qLpCsvMViuY9UjgxTobllwTGY4aa . I hope I am doing it right. I am new to this forum and I am still trying to learn how to move around

Comment: Welcome @jose.novas! You should use the link in the first comment to upload your file, then [edit] your question to add the link. Check [ask] and take the [tour] if you want to learn more about the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the following changes:

- Remove the second render layer, because it doesn't contribute anything to the compositing result and doubles the render time.
- Use *Branched Path Tracing* with high samples for the diffuse sub samples and mesh lights and low samples for everything else. This reduces the noise significantly.

If you would be switching to the most recent version of Blender you could also use Open Image Denoise, which can reduce the required samples significantly.

[image]

Comment: Hi Robert! THANK YOU!!!!your tips worked like a charm. I went from almost 5 minutes render time per frame to barely 2. I tried to render in blender 2.8  but the rockgenerator node that I applied produced crazy artifacts in the geometry.  This is probably caused by the bad modelling. Coming from Max and Vray there is a lot I have to learn and I am still trying to get used to the new intergace and workflow. Once again, thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Great! If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.